# Is it possible to list a YouTube Channel's uploaded videos?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

So I'm working on my website and I wanted to create a list of recently uploaded videos on my channel. I can do it manually but I wanted to know if there was a way to automate it, maybe a script or something. I tried looking up the YouTube API but I can't find something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube has rss feeds for the uploaded videos on a channel that is available at a URL like

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCmv1CLT6ZcFdTJMHxaR9XeA
```

You didn't mention anything else about the site you want to use this for, but there are many ways to use an RSS feed.

Comment: I want to use the website as my main website. I wanted list some of my recent uploads on my website. Also can you tell me some ways to implement these?